# can we auto detect the feature type as nominal or ordinal in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, feature-selection

I am working on a project where I want to detect the feature as nominal or ordinal type through a python script without any human intervention. Is this possible.

I am new to data science. your comments will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column like 'Age' does not represent nominal or ordinal data, but numerical data. You can find all columns that contain numerical data by using:

```
numeric_cols = df._get_numeric_data().columns  # numeric columns
cols = df.columns  # all columns
```

Let's say that columns that are not numeric are either nominal or ordinal (for example Gender) than you can find these columns with:

```
categorical_cols = list(set(cols) - set(numeric_cols))
```

If you want to identify nominal versus ordinal data, you would need to define some method for doing so. For example if you have ordinal data for clothing size (small, medium, large) you would have to define a fixed order first.

Comment: lets I have a dataframe with gender column in which i have male and female entries. Also there is another column Age. I want the script which can detect that whether the gender and age are nominal or ordinal. As a human it is easy but what if a script do so?

Comment: Thank you... then i think i have to define some order first.